# reference to type 'Item *const' could not bind to an rvalue of type 'const Item *'

Tags: c++, list, qt, pointers, constants

I try to suppress a `const` item pointer from a list of none `const` item:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QList>

class Item {
public:
    Item(QString name) : _name(name) {
    }
private:
    QString _name;
};

class Product {
public:
    Product(const Item * item) : _item(item) {
    }

    const Item * item() {
        return _item;
    }

    void setItem(const Item * item) {
        _item = item;
    }
private:
    const Item * _item;
};

int main() {
    QList<Item*> listOfNonConstItem;
    listOfNonConstItem.append(new Item("a"));
    listOfNonConstItem.append(new Item("b"));

    Product product(listOfNonConstItem.first());
    listOfNonConstItem.removeOne(product.item());

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, the compiler fails:

```
/path/to/main.cpp:34:31: error: reference to type 'Item *const' could not bind to an lvalue of type 'const Item *'
    editableList.removeOne(pC);
                           ^~
/path/to/Qt/5.6.3/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qlist.h:201:29: note: passing argument to parameter 't' here
bool removeOne(const T &t);
                        ^
```

I don't understand why there is a problem since `removeOne()` parameter is `const`.

Comment: Don't confuse the pointee with the pointer.

Comment: What do you mean by pointee?

Comment: The object type being pointed *to*. Expressed in the pointer type as whatever is before the asterisk `*`.

Comment: @LogicStuff I just edited my example so the line number match

Comment: @StoryTeller Ok so what am I confusing? (I updated my question by the way)

Comment: I still think you misunderstand what the placement of `const` means in your types. For one, `_item` has the const qualified type, the pointer, not the pointee. So why do you try to assign to it?

Comment: And by the way, adding an entirely separate question into your post, after someone helped you solve the original one (and you even acknowledge the original is solved by the answer bellow), is bad Stack Overflow etiquette. I suggest you revert the edit, accept the answer, and post a new question.

Comment: @StoryTeller Ok I revert my edit! Sorry for the annoying modification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing with `const` pointer and pointer to `const`.

What `removeOne` expects is the pointer(i.e. `Item*`); for the parameter declaration, `const` is qualifed on the pointer but not the pointee (i.e. `Item* const &`, reference to const pointer to non-const `Item`). While what you're passing is a pointer to `const` (i.e. `const Item*`), which can't be converted to pointer to non-const implicitly.

Changing the type of `pC` to `Item*` or `Item* const` would solve the issue.

Comment: This fixed my example but in fact what I want to do is a little more complex. I updated my code to better explain what I want to do.

Comment: I will revert my edit since you solved my first problem!